Row bind multiple data frames in dictionary using dict.keys() as column 1 of output pd.df
i found a way to concatenate my pandas data frames in a dictionary.
Que; how can i use the dictionary keys as first column in the final dataframe?
i tried but thar didn't work
pd.concat(test_list.values(), ignore_index=False, keys= test_list.keys())

data
test_list = {'ENSMUSG00000025333.10':         treatment_code  subjectCode  fraction_modified_entropy_in_log2  log_RPKM
59478                0            2                           1.822939  3.109444
107087               1            4                           0.811278  3.476707, 'ENSMUSG00000025903.14':         treatment_code  subjectCode  fraction_modified_entropy_in_log2  log_RPKM
178498               0            1                           1.000000  3.175110
107116               1            3                           3.551271  3.002025, 'ENSMUSG00000063663.11':         treatment_code  subjectCode  fraction_modified_entropy_in_log2  log_RPKM
59417                0            2                           2.755851   1.07040
118918               1            3                           3.088372   1.19147}


You can reset_index after concat, optionally setting a name with name=['desired name']:
out = (pd.concat(test_list.values(), ignore_index=False,
                 keys= test_list.keys(),
                 names=['col1'])
         .reset_index(0)
      )

Note that since you already have a dictionary, you can pass it directly instead of using .keys()/.values():
out = (pd.concat(test_list, ignore_index=False,
                 names=['col1'])
         .reset_index(0)
      )

Output:
                         col1  treatment_code  subjectCode  fraction_modified_entropy_in_log2  log_RPKM
59478   ENSMUSG00000025333.10               0            2                           1.822939  3.109444
107087  ENSMUSG00000025333.10               1            4                           0.811278  3.476707
178498  ENSMUSG00000025903.14               0            1                           1.000000  3.175110
107116  ENSMUSG00000025903.14               1            3                           3.551271  3.002025
59417   ENSMUSG00000063663.11               0            2                           2.755851  1.070400
118918  ENSMUSG00000063663.11               1            3                           3.088372  1.191470

